# JavaScript split function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using the split function in JavaScript.  It  works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but IE displays an error when I call the split function.  Is there a way to use other function like split?

Comment: Need to see your code and what is the error you're getting?

Comment: It does support, it probably fails on something else in your code. Post your code and we'll see.

Comment: We will reply as fast as you can paste your code. Please select your code after paste and click the button with {}

Comment: what version of IE are you testing with? (this is important, as there are bugs with `split()` in older versions of IE)

Comment: @mplungjan - in some older versions of IE, if you split a string and it has separator characters immediately adjacent to each other, it won't return the empty element. eg `"x||y".split('|')` gives an array with only two results "x" and "y" rather than three. I believe it was IE6 that did this; I don't have a copy of IE6 any more to verify this, but I remember it causing me huge problems a few years ago until I found out about the bug.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Interesting since I have never run into any bugs with split since 1996 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5az126b(v=vs.85).aspx)

It's fully supported by IE8

[split method for JScript 5.6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5az126b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

It's also fully supported by IE6

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/UqAET/3/) using `.split(/\s+/)`

Tested in IE9 standards, IE9 IE8 mode, IE9 IE7 mode and IE9 quirks mode. All work.

**Edit:**

Turns out your actual problem is using `.textContent`. This does not work in IE. There are two alternatives.

**Feature detection:**

```
var str;
if (el.textContent) {
  str = el.textContent;
} else {
  str = el.innerText;
}
```

**.nodeValue:**

`var str = el.nodeValue;`

Comment: i understand my problem i use that code       textContent.split(/\s+/);       so textcontent working in ff and crome but not working in ie . solution is use innertext which is not working in ff so is there any other solution

Comment: @VbPatel Yes `.textContent` is not supported. Use `.nodeValue`

Answer (score 1):

When you split a number instead of String, Javascript throws - Object doesn't support this property.

Make sure you have a string value in var.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one difference between IE below #9 and most other browsers when dealing with string splitting-

var s='In some browsers, you can "split" a  string on a parenthized delimeter and return the "split-off" bits in the array.';

```
s.split(/( ?['"] ?)/).join('\n')

/***************************************************/
Firefox 4.0.1>>
 In some browsers, you can
 "
split
" 
a  string on a parenthized delimeter and return the
 "
split-off
" 
bits in the array.
/***************************************************/    
MSIE 8.0>>
 In some browsers, you can
split
a  string on a parenthized delimeter and return the
split-off
bits in the array.
/***************************************************/    
MSIE 9.0>>
 In some browsers, you can
 "
split
" 
a  string on a parenthized delimeter and return the
 "
split-off
" 
bits in the array.
```