# How to Split a dynamic variable into drop down box ( variable seperated by comma)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

var device_name = sreeni , murtuza , deepu , bharath , ...... n th number

i need to split this Variable  based on the comma and put it in a drop down box.

example:

```
    sreeni

    murtuza

    deepu

    bhatah
```

Please provide a solution using through Javascript  or Jquery

Comment: Thanks Every one one special thanks to Shiplu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With plain JS,

```
var device_name = "sreeni , murtuza , deepu , bharath"
var list = device_name.split(/\s*,\s*/);
var dd = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
for(var i = 0; i< list.length; i++){
    dd.innerHTML += '<option value="'+list[i]+'">'+list[i]+'</option>';
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UYbR7/2)

More Hacky way,

```
document
.getElementById("myDropDown2")
.innerHTML = device_name
             .replace(
                 /\w+/g,
                 function(m){
                     return '<option value="'+m+'">'+m+'</option>'
                 }
             )
             .replace(/\s*,\s*/g,'');
```

Comment: Note: .split() is not supported by ie

Comment: Agree, the second one is very nice.

Comment: Thanks Shiplu. your saving my 2 days time..Hope more helpfull comments from you.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var myListOfWords = "apple,orange,bananna,cherries";
   var list = myListOfWords.split(",");


    var dd = document.getElementById("myDropDown");

    for(var i = 0; i< list.length; i++){
        var objOption = document.createElement("option");
        objOption.text = list[i]
        dd.add(objOption) ;
    }
```

//and somewhere in your html

```
<select id="myDropDown"/>
```

Here's the working example: [dynamic drop down fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yFCyL/)

Comment: click the fiddle link and decide for yourself :)

Comment: oh, and welcome to Stack! Please up-vote the answers you like and mark as correct the ones that you feel best answered your question.

Comment: I have commented before you edited it. :) treating options as an array will not work. But this edit is good.

Comment: actually, treating options as an array is perfectly valid... elements[i].options[i].text and so forth.  IE doesn't support split()? Are you certain?

Comment: not sure what you're talking about... apparently supported fully as far back as v7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422355/javascript-split-function-not-working-in-ie  before that IE6 basically didn't support anything at all... who's the maniac still trying to keep the masochists using it in style?

Answer (score 1):

```
var strings = "sreeni,murtuza,deepu,bhatah";
var splitStrings = strings.split();
var selectObj = document.createElement("option");
for (var i in splitStrings) {
    selectObj.options[selectObj.options.length] = new Option(splitStrings[i], splitStrings[i]);
}

document.getElementById("idOfElementToContainDropdown").appendChild(selectObj);
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 1):

```
    var names = device_name.split(",");
    var combo = document.getElementById("comboId");
    //for i = 1 to length of names list {
    var item = document.createElement("OPTION");
    item.text=names[i];
    combo.options.add(item);
}
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: .split() is not supported by ie

Comment: Travis, you're mistaken. it's entirely supported and has been for years.

Comment: .split() is very buggy, I am surprised it worked for you but do not expect it to always work. See this article: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$('#myDropDown').empty();
$.each(device_name.split(","), function(iIndex, sElement) {
    if  ($.trim(sElement).length > 0) {
        $('#myDropDown').append('<option>' + $.trim(sElement) + '</option>');
    }
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3XaVZ/2/).

Comment: var device_name = $(this).parent().parent().find('.member').html(); This is a table value,first cell contain sreeni,murtuza,. when i click $(this) i get first cell value sreeni, murtuza. Same as in second cell contain value "deepu,Bhatrth" .when i click $(this) i get "deepu,bharth,". etc...nth cell .In this situation your code adding a null value, when i click 1 st cell its properly coming sreeni and murtuza in drop down box but after murtuza i can select a null value too. double click append same value twice. How can i avoid this situation. Thnaks in advance

Comment: This will work well with static value. But its fails in dynamic situation. DOM value always a break my head.any how thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: Yes now no null values but am sorry why its appending  same value twice when ever i click $(this). i try same code with .html() too. hope my problem is more complicated.