# Is there any standard which says if "aba".split(/a/) should return 1,2, or 3 elements?

Tags: javascript, string, split

From what I've tested

```
"aba".split(/a/).length
```

returns

- 1 in ie8
- 3 in firefox, chrome, opera

I was always prepared to handle differences in DOM manipulation, or Events model, but I've thought that things like strings, regexps, etc. are well defined. Was I wrong?

Comment: Good question. _"Was I wrong?"_ - Evidently you were. But you're not the only one who's been caught out by this. When I tried IE9 it returned `3` but only when not running in IE7 or IE8 document mode...

Comment: I was going to blame IE8, but IE9 (in IE9 mode in an empty document) returns `1` as well.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453521, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422355 and http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

Comment: Apparently you were wrong. Question, though: Is this just a example or regex usage in `string.split`? Because just splitting on `"a"` would be more efficient in this case.

Comment: @Cerbrus: there is no invalidity in using regular expressions for splitting.

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky: I didn't say that. But if you're doing a simple split on -one- character, using a regex is kindof overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE removes from the `split` result array all undefined or empty strings.

As your question seems to be about the existence of a standard, then EcmaScript is the best match in the Javascript world.

And the behavior of split on regex *is* documented : http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14

As it obvious from the example, empty strings should not be removed from the resulting array, so IE (as suspected) is faulty.

```
"A<B>bold</B>and<CODE>coded</CODE>".split(/<(\/)?([^<>]+)>/)

    evaluates to the array

["A", undefined, "B", "bold", "/", "B", "and", undefined,  "CODE", "coded", "/", "CODE", ""]
```

In fact, there are other differences between browsers. A solution could be to use a [cross-browser split regex script](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split) but it's probably better to be simply aware of the differences and handle with proper tests the array returned by `split`. Or use some tricks.